# Merge 3 cells in 1 with VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel

The below code is working uses formula to concatenate the result from `Range("K:M")` and write the result in column H.

Is there a better way to write the below code that can concatenate the result to the exact location as per below table? Please note that data in the before table is discontinued but sometimes will be from row 4 to 1000 rows down or the below example.

```
Sub GenerateStyleFabricColourV4()
    Dim srcData As Range
    Dim rowNum As Long, lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets(2)
        lastRow = Application.Max(4, _
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row, _
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row, _
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
        With .Cells(4, "H").Resize(lastRow - 4 + 1, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[3]&rc[4]&rc[5]"
            .Value = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Sub ClearAllData()

Rows("4:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: I suppose it works for you, but it's very difficult for us to review it without knowing your data. (e.g. depending on your data table, you may use `range.currentregion` instead of the multiple `end(xlup)` calls.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Will post the data as soon as i get home sorry about that.

Comment: Would you clearly say what's your question?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Just updated the data table.

Comment: @QuickSilver If my answer resolve the problem for you please consider reviewing it and marking as accepted to help the other users find their answers later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer another question I provided some helpful information about optimization in vba here, [VBA syntax that compiles sub data into master sheet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159298/vba-syntax-that-compiles-sub-data-into-master-sheet/160569#160569).

This maybe help you to skip the blank rows (You did not clarify your question but based on the data you provided I think that would be your problem) and find the actual last row used. It is in reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077059/vba-find-last-row-of-a-specific-range-of-columns). Here's the code:

```
Dim srcData As Range, rng As Range
Dim rowNum As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim wsh As Worksheet

Sub GSFC_V4()
 Set wsh = Worksheets(2)
 
 wsh.Activate
 Set srcData = Range("K:M")
 Set rng = Range("K4")


 With wsh 
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
     lastrow = srcData.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=rng, _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
 Else
     lastrow = 1  
 End If


     With .Cells(4, "H").Resize(lastRow - 4 + 1, 1)
         .FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[3]&rc[4]&rc[5]"
         .Value = .Value2
     End With
 End With

End Sub
```

This is what I am using to optimize my macros. I call `OptimizeVBA True` at the beginning of each macro and at the end call `OptimizeVBA False` to set everything back to default. It increases the performance remarkably.

```
Sub OptimizeVBA(isOn As Boolean)

  Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
  Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
  Application.StatusBar = Not (isOn)

End Sub
```

You need to be careful of how you refer to ranges to avoid getting errors.

Comment: Gives a run time error 1000 on the ` With .Cells(4, "H").Resize(lastRow - 4 + 1, 1)` can't work out why.

Comment: @QuickSilver This is not the optimized way to do it but you can try this: before that "With block" add this `.Cells(4, "H").Select` and substitute the `.Cells(4,"H").` with `Selection.`. You may need to put the second with block out of the first one (i.e. `With wsh`).

Answer (score 1):

I had an old script on hand that accomplished most of what I think you're after, though it uses a different approach.  I modified it and it seems to work with your data.  You'll need to update at least a couple values in the code — see comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GSFC_V4()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("ConcatTest.xlsx") 'update workbook name

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'update worksheet name

Dim TextS As String
Dim TextF As String
Dim TextC As String

Dim StartRow As Long
StartRow = 5 'assumes row 5 is the first row containing data to be concatenated
Dim LastRow As Long, lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long, lRow3 As Long
lRow1 = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow3 = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(lRow1, lRow2, lRow3)

Dim CheckCell As Range
Dim ConcatRange As Range
Set ConcatRange = Range(ws.Cells(StartRow, "K"), ws.Cells(LastRow, "K"))

Dim i As Long
i = StartRow

For Each CheckCell In ConcatRange
  TextS = ws.Cells(i, "K").Value
  TextF = ws.Cells(i, "L").Value
  TextC = ws.Cells(i, "M").Value
  i = i + 1
  If Not CheckCell.Value = "" Then
    CheckCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = TextS & TextF & TextC
  End If
Next CheckCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```